how to add support for language Lean 4 in Lyx program listings
I was very pleased with Lyx's ability to include program listings, and to syntax highlight them too.
My current project is about the Lean 4 programming language.
Lyx 2.3.8 (latest) supports many languages but not Lean 4.
How can I add support for it?

Update - I have been pointed to this language definition file
https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/master/doc/latex/lstlean.tex
I've placed it in /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings
and run texthash
but I have not succeeded in making it appear in the Lyx GUI list of program listing languages.
